# Show result in view in percent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a database containing of customers, articles, invoices and so on. In MSSQL Server Management Studio I've created a View to show the sale in the invoices and inovoice lines.

Two of the columns in the Invoice table is Sales tax and Discount, that both is in decimals (eg. 0,25 instead of 25%), but in the View I want to show it as percentage. The problem is that I just can't figure out how to do it, so is there any kind soul out there that might be able to help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Article.AricleID, dbo.Article.Artname, 
    dbo.Invoiceline.Quantity, dbo.Invoiceline.Price, dbo.Invoiceline.Discount, 
    dbo.Salestax.Salestax
FROM  dbo.Article 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Invoiceline ON dbo.Article.AricleID = dbo.Invoiceline.ArticleID 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Invoice ON dbo.Invoiceline.InvoiceID = dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Salestax ON dbo.Invoiceline.SalestaxID = dbo.Salestax.SalestaxID
ORDER BY dbo.Invoice.Date
```

Comment: The join to `dbo.Invoice` seems to serve no purpose (I'm assuming you're going to follow my advice and remove the `top/order by`). There are no output columns or anything else that reference `dbo.Invoice`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, remove the `TOP (100) PERCENT` and the `ORDER BY` from your view definition. They do not guarantee any order unless you are using a specific trace flag to restore SQL Server 2000 functionality - and if you are still using that trace flag, you shouldn't be. If you want the results of your queries from this view to come back in a certain order, then add `ORDER BY` to those queries.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
    SELECT 
      a.AricleID, a.Artname, il.Quantity, il.Price,
      Discount = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 100*il.Discount) + '%',
      Salestax = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 100*s.Salestax) + '%'
    FROM
      dbo.Article AS a
      INNER JOIN dbo.Invoiceline AS il
      ON il.AricleID = il.ArticleID 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Invoice AS i
      ON il.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Salestax AS s
      ON il.SalestaxID = s.SalestaxID;
```

A couple of other comments:

- you really should be applying formatting at the presentation layer - it isn't SQL Server's job and you also may not want to presume anything about the end user's regional settings.
- you need to be careful about storing the tax ID in the table, rather than the actual tax charged. If tax rates change over time, then your historical data is not going to be accurate if they're pointing at the same tax id but the rate has changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer and advices, really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

assuming your amounts are stored as numbers, you just multiply by 100 to get the % value.

```
SELECT  dbo.Article.AricleID, dbo.Article.Artname, dbo.Invoiceline.Quantity,   
dbo.Invoiceline.Price, dbo.Invoiceline.Discount * 100, dbo.Salestax.Salestax *100
```

if you want to add the % sign as well, use something like this for each value

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(dbo.Invoiceline.Discount * 100)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply your values by 100, I added some aliases as well for easier reading.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT A.AricleID, A.Artname, IL.Quantity, IL.Price
    , IL.Discount * 100 As Discount
    , S.Salestax * 100 As SalesTax
FROM  dbo.Article A
INNER JOIN dbo.Invoiceline IL
    ON A.AricleID = IL.ArticleID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Invoice I 
    ON IL.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Salestax S 
    ON IL.SalestaxID = S.SalestaxID
ORDER BY I.Date
```